# How to detect the current release track inside the android app?(Google Play Console)

Tags: android, google-play-console, instabug

I am planning to release my app to beta track before the prod. But I would like to enable in-app-bug reporting only for the beta users. Instead of creating two APKs(enabled in prod beta & disabled in prod), can I know programmatically from which track user has installed the app, is there any API available for that?

what I want to achieve is,

```
if(app installed from beta track)
  enable in-app-bug reporting
else 
  disable in-app-bug reporting
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348?hl=en#zippy=%2Crelease-name):

> The release name is only for use in Play Console and won't be visible to users.

Answer (score -3):

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "in_app_bug", true
    }

    staging {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "in_app_bug", true
    }

    release {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "in_app_bug", false
    }
}
```

then in the code:

```
if(BuildConfig.in_app_bug) {
  ....
}
```

The same can be done for `buildFlavors`

Comment: I think what christian-z meant, was in the same binary how could you detect what release track the app was downloaded from.